# Crash on DeviceIoControl call

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-7, windows-10

I'm trying to get partitions offset on my HDD. I do it this way:

```
PDRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX partitions;
DWORD partitionsSize = sizeof(DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX) 
                       + 127 * sizeof(PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX);
partitions = (PDRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX)malloc(partitionsSize);

HANDLE h = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", FILE_ANY_ACCESS , 
                      FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, 
                      OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
   // handle error and exit
}
if (DeviceIoControl(h, IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX, NULL, 0, partitions, 
                    partitionsSize, 0, NULL) != 0)
{
   // do stuff with partitions here
}
```

It works fine on Windows 10, but fails on Windows 7 (on DeviceIoControl call). Debugger output is: `Exception at 0x7fefcc3b2b2, code: 0xc0000005: write access violation at: 0x1, flags=0x0`

I tried: run as admin, change file access parameters on CreateFile, google (maybe not good enough)

I use: Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0

Comment: one of the last 2 params (`lpBytesReturned` or `lpOverlapped`) must not be 0. and visual studio version, run as admin, change file access parameters on CreateFile - can not affect access violation on `DeviceIoControl`

Comment: @RbMm, thanks. It solves problem!

Answer (score 2):

I read docs inattentively. The answer is in comments (answered by @RbMm)

> one of the last 2 params (lpBytesReturned or lpOverlapped) must not be
>   0. and visual studio version, run as admin, change file access parameters on CreateFile - can not affect access violation on